# Creating VirtualMachine in macOS app - com.apple.vm.networking entitlements

Tags: swift, xcode, networking, virtualization

I want to create a macOS terminal application that will utilize `Virtualization` framework and run `Linux` inside. I learned that to use networking in this machine, I need `com.apple.vm.networking` entitlement. I contacted `Apple` and this entitlement was added to my team. How can I now use it? I already checked in on `developer portal` in `provisioning profile`, but I have no idea how to configure `Xcode project`. I tried adding this `com.apple.vm.networking` in `entitlements file`, but it usually causes app to crash after start with error code 9.

Comment: You need to add the vmnet framework. See the apple docs for how it's used.

Comment: This worked finally when I switched from command line application to MacOS app.